# nth Bar after a timestamp in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am new to pine script. I want to draw a vertical line after n-bars from a given timestamp in any timeframe.

lets say I have set timestamp as

```
startTime = input.time(timestamp("9 Feb 2023 00:00 +05:00"), "Start")
```

now I want to draw a vertical line for a candle which comes after 11 candle in any timeframe from given startTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the candle time at the desired offset with the given timestamp and execute the line with `line.new()` function with the same `x1` and `x2` arguments:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

startTime = input.time(timestamp("9 Feb 2023 00:00 +05:00"), "Start")

bars = input.int(11)

if startTime == time[bars]
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close + 1, extend = extend.both)
```